# Make wordpress page full width with Divi

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Is it possible to have my webpage with Divi be the full width of the browser window instead of the way it is set up now, centered at about 80% width?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to deactive the "box layout" option and use fullwidth sections/modules